# node-webkit How to parse 'open' event parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments, node-webkit

I need an array with all the arguments like the value in gui.App.argv
Is there some function included to parse this?

```
function openfile(cmdline){
    console.log('command line: ' + cmdline);
}
openfile(gui.App.argv); //my file.txt, my file.txt  (this is what I need)
gui.App.on('open', function(cmdline) {
    openfile(cmdline);  //app.exe --original-process-start-time=13049249391168190 "my file.txt" "my file2.txt"
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue, here is how i solved it:

```
// Listen to `open` event
gui.App.on('open', function (cmdline) {
   // Break out the params from the command line
   var arr = /(.*)--original-process-start-time\=(\d+)(.*)/.exec(cmdline);

   // Get the last match and split on spaces
   var params = arr.pop().split(' ');

   console.log('Array of parameters', params);
});
```

This will work as long as they don't change the output structure of the event (i.e the **--original-process-start-time** flag)
but if and when they do i would look into doing this using the **process.execPath** maybe

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
1. Replace all spaces in quotes by somethink like "& nbsp;" (HTML space).
2. Split string by spaces.
3. Replace "& nbsp;" by space.

```
gui.App.on('open', function(cmdline) {
    cmdline = cmdline.replace(/"([^"]+)"/g, function(a) {
        return a.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;"); 
    }).split(' ');
    for (var i = 0, length = cmdline.length, arg = '', args = []; i < length; ++i) {
        arg = cmdline[i].replace(/&nbsp;/g, ' ');
        // Filter by exe file and exe args.
        if (arg === '"' + process.execPath + '"' || arg.search(/^\-\-/) === 0) continue;
        args.push(arg);
    }
    console.log(args);
});
```

Work on 0.14.x, 0.15.x.